# Routing Areas in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, area

I have a user area and I want to remove the controller from user Area URL

I tried using

```
[Route("User/ChangePassword")
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
```

but it doesnt work!

RouteConfig

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

UserAreaRegistration

```
 public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "User";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "User_default",
                "User/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

So How can I generate this url for user area?

domain.com/user/changepassword

Answer (score 0):

You can add namespace in the Route.config. It will point to the area's configuration path

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] {
                "Areas.Controllers"
            }
            );
        }
```